# Java Web Service HttpServletRequestWrapper Issue: IllegalStateException

Tags: java, http, request, illegalstateexception

I am currently developing a RESTful Webservice in Java using the Jersey library.

For security reasons, we want a custom authentication similar to Amazons Simple Storage Service. This requires, however, that I calculate an MD5 hash of the body (if there is any) to authenticate the request.

So far, I have used a custom Authenticator and Realm and plugged them into my context.
Upon trying to calculate the hash I first used the request itself resulting in an IllegalStateException, since the body can only be read once.

After investigating the problem I tried to wrap the request inside a HttpServletRequestWrapper but hasn't been successful so far.

I am basically using a wrapper like the one shown here:
http://forums.oracle.com/forums/thread.jspa?threadID=2156814&tstart=0

Inside my realm, where I do the authentication, I am first creating the wrapper like so:

```
MyRequestWrapper requestWrapper = new MyRequestWrapper(request);
```

then I am calculating the MD5 using the requestWrapper
and finally forwarding it

```
request.getRequestDispatcher("/*").forward(requestWrapper, response);
```

The processing works fine but I get an error like this after that:

```
Servlet.service() for servlet Jersey REST Service threw exception
java.lang.IllegalStateException
    at org.apache.catalina.connector.ResponseFacade.sendError(ResponseFacade.java:407)
    at com.sun.jersey.spi.container.servlet.WebComponent$Writer.finish(WebComponent.java:285)
    at com.sun.jersey.spi.container.ContainerResponse.write(ContainerResponse.java:241)
```

Note that there is no mentioning of the getReader or getInputStream being called before (like I got without using any wrapper at all).

Now I am sure I am doing something wrong here but I really don't know much about this and would be really glad if someone could help me out here :)

Best Regards,
Lukas

Comment: Does the exception has a *cause* logged?

Comment: I suppose you mean what would normally be after java.lang.IllegalStateException. And no, it just appears like that without a cause after IllegalStateException.

Comment: are you directly accessing the response output stream at any point in your processing?

Comment: I was accessing getReader() from the request. Response I did not touch. However I found that the problem was forwarding the wrapper. I didn't explicitly state this in my question but I am using tomcat and tried to use the above code inside a valve. I am still interested in the question if this is also possible from a valve, since this fits better into the tomcat model.
I have now moved to using a filter which is not so nice, but works.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As stated in my comment to my question:

> I was accessing getReader() from the request. Response I did not touch. However I found  that the problem was forwarding the wrapper. I didn't explicitly state this in my question but I am using tomcat and tried to use the above code inside a valve. I am still interested in the question if this is also possible from a valve, since this fits better into the tomcat model. I have now moved to using a filter which is not so nice, but works

I found however that this solution is quite nice (using a filter) instead of a tomcat valve.